# Prestashop Axon social login facebook redirect page is not exist

Tags: facebook, prestashop

Prestashop version is 1.7.8.0. I have installed Axon Soical Login plugin. It has Facebook OAuth support. So I want to use its OAuth login for the client login. I enabled it and filled in the Facebook ID and Secret, it shows up https://[www.domain.com]/module/nrtsociallogin/facebook as OAuth redirect link. I pasted it into Facebook OAuth redirect URL setting and check the URL, return failed. So I pasted it into browser, return 404.

Obviously, the error is caused by OAuth redirect page does not exist! How to fix it?

Comment: _"I have installed Axon Soical Login plugin."_ - can't find any plugin by that name. Link to docs, please?

Comment: This seems to be a third party module , so best option would be to refer to its developer for support. However if "/module/nrtsociallogin/facebook" route is returning 404, being it a front controller my guess is that the module is for some reason disabled.

Comment: Here is that document. http://axonvip.com/nrtsociallogin/facebook/ The only support email I can find on their website is demo@axonvip.com. I have sent an email asking them the question. But they didn't respond.

Comment: I found the workaround. I just use "Traffic & SEO" in Prestashop admin platform to create a new page, page name chooses "nrfsociallogin - facebook", and rewritten URL choose "facebook_login". Then I add the domain.com/facekbook_login in the valid oauth redirect URL on facebook developer's login setting page. It works.